# Is it possible to change EL base on the selected value from dropdown list?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

```
<th>
  <h:outputText value="Pending Actions" style="font-weight:bold" />
    <td colspan="4">
      <p:selectOneMenu value="#{selectedValue}" required="true">
         <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="--Select One--" />
         <f:selectItem itemValue="organization1" itemLabel="ORGANIZAION1" />
         <f:selectItem itemValue="organization2" itemLabel="ORGANIZAION2" />
         <f:selectItem itemValue="organization3" itemLabel="ORGANIZAION3" />
         <f:selectItem itemValue="organization4" itemLabel="ORGANIZAION4" />
       </p:selectOneMenu>
  <h:inputTextarea value="#{casesBean.organization1PendingActionDetails}"/>
 </td>
</th>
```

As shown above, there is a dropdown list to let users select which organization they want to assign task.

- In my database, there are columns
  `organization1PendingActionDetails`,
  `organization2PendingActionDetails`, etc.
- So my question is:

  Is it possible to change the `inputTextarea` value
          based on the selected value from the dropdown list?
- For example:

If the user selected **organization2** then the `inputTextarea` will become 
 `value="#{casesBean.organization2PendingActionDetails}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need to have more than one **inputTextarea**. Each area should have different value, and rendered set based on selected value. After selection set proper rendered value on **inputTextarea** and update it via ajax.

```
<p:ajax event="change" listener=#{casesBean.decideRenderedInputTextArea} update="InputTextAreasWrapper" />
```

**Better solution:**
It is way more elegant to have one **inputTextArea**. As you said you want to store the values from it into the database. So decide where to store data based on selected value inside been before performing action which will store data into database (after submit form).

Comment: @vennis Then consider close this topic by accepting the answer.